# Where can I download free or open access census datasets for China, including their respective spatial boundaries?

Tags: data, census

I am interested in the equivalent of US Census Bureau open data and its relevant Tigerline spatial data, albeit for China. In Canada, we also have data released by Statistics Canada along with cartographic reference boundaries.

I should make it clear that I am having trouble navigating the Chinese National Bureau of Statistics website, http://www.stats.gov.cn/english/. It may be in fact that this website does not offer any free data, but it is located elsewhere?

Most importantly, I am looking for free/open data!

Comment: download from http://chinadataonline.org/member/censussearch/ need to register/login

Comment: I am also looking for socio-economic data like you are...I believe Mapperz' reply was a link to old data and it requires log-in information?

Comment: I feel that @BradNesom Link is not a duplicate, since this question specifically asks about Census Data, while that one asks for Administrative and other general data.